# How to identify Outlook's "Out of office" autoreply?

Tags: email, outlook, email-headers

I'm working on a mail server that receives messages from users. I want to be able to filter Outlook's "Out of office" autoreply messages. It seems that there's no special header in those messages, so it seems that the only option is to identify them by the subject line (they start with "Out of office AutoReply").

But identifying using the subject line has it's issues too, for example -- what if the users has a different locale and the text will be in a different language?

Has anyone tackled this before and has a better way to identify those messages? (or the list of translations :))

Comment: Looking at OoO messages here coming from Exchange 2007 indicates that they start with "Out of Office:". I think subject line is definitely out. Good luck with this, not sure how you will do it.

Comment: Thanks, added it as another test case... for now I will have to use the string matching option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe JAMES has a method for identifying out of office replies. I used to work for a small ESP and that's what we used to send email and parse responses we'd get.

Comment: JAMES is an open-source java-based mail platform. [JAMES](http://james.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late to reply to this but Outlook now has a rule condition called "is an automatic reply" which can be used to filter out Out of Office replies

Comment: That's not relevant: I was looking to identify Outlook's own automatic replies, and not how to configure Outlook detect automatic replies...

Comment: But presumably it knows how... so there must be a way.